# Unable to add cookie using Selenium::Remote::Driver

Tags: selenium

I am unable to add a cookie using this module.

Even when I use a simple example .. 
$driver->add_cookie('foo','bar','/','my_server',0);

I get error :

(Error while executing command: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.: given 'cookie' parameters are invalid (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
 Command duration or timeout: 20 milliseconds
 Build info: version: '2.24.1', revision: '17205', time: '2012-06-19 17:28:14'
 System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_13'
 Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
 Session ID: cdbf4aca4034937573ca0cea4a9e5977 at C:/workspace/ST/t/TestCl.pm line 21.)

I also tried spoofing a real looking domain name in my hosts file and pointing it to the server. However it was not helpful at all.

Plz help .

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this the cookies have to be in a dictionary as such:

```
add_cookie({‘name’ : ‘foo’, ‘value’ : ‘bar’, ‘path’ : ‘/’})
```